# IE, Почему не вызывается событие при записи большого массива в LocalStorage?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, localstorage

```
<html>
<head>

</head>
<body>
    <script>
        var storage = window.localStorage;

        function readStoredData(event) {

            var key = event.key;
            var newValue = event.newValue;

            if (key == "testData") {
                var newData = JSON.parse(newValue);
                console.log("New Data: " + newData.length);
            }

            if (key == "testString") {
                console.log("String: " + newValue);
            }
        }

        window.addEventListener("storage", readStoredData, false);


        var data = [];

        for (var i = 0; i < 200; i++) {
            data.push({
                id: i,
                message: "Message №" + i
            });
        }

        storage.setItem("testData", JSON.stringify(data));

        storage.setItem("testString", "string");

    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

При сохранении небольшой строки, событие генерируется, но когда пытаюсь сохранить большой массив, событие не генерируется, причем массив сохраняется.

P.s. браузер IE

Comment: Ваш код в IE версия 11.0.9600.17843 работает стабильно.

Answer (score 1):

Потому что IE - грустно.

События хранилищ в IE 10-11 очень забагованы, и если есть какая-то возможность сделать без них - лучше сделать без них. Это - один из встречающихся багов.

Если очень надо таки писать что-то большое в localStorage - придется писать по кускам, как например [тут](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21139931/ie11-doesnt-fire-local-storage-events-when-value-is-too-large).

Кстати, для тех кому надо работать с хранилищами в IE, несколько известных неприятностей с localStorage в осле описаны на [caniuse.com](http://caniuse.com/#search=localstorage)